# Add a draggable slider on highcharts to drop a flag

Tags: jquery, d3.js, svg, highcharts

I have to allow user to drop flags on the chart.

For this I wish to provide him a slider on the top of graph which the person can drag horizontally and select the date where he/she wants to drop the flag. The form associated with the drag button captures the date and user can enter some desired details. Once user clicks 'Drop', the flag shall be created on x-axis at the desired date.

The image here explains what I want to achieve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg7om.png

I know highcharts fairly but couldn't get through the best way of doing this.
I have looked at Draggable points and Annotation plug-ins (which has call backs etc.). I have also looked at the renderer, however am not good at handling them.

Please help and guide me on this. A rough working would be great, I can fair it from there.

Thanks,
SS

Comment: Generally when you have a annotations and appropriate callbacks, you can develop that. Inside functions, you need to develop a logic which show/hide your custom form and trigger actions.

Comment: Ok. So using annotation would be better. Thanks. How do I create the slider and keep moving the form along with the slider?

Comment: By slider you mean a bottom navigator or something different?

Comment: No, slider at the top. If you look at the image it shows a green line and a button. I want to slide the button horizontally over that line (or at least give an impression). 

By sliding it user can move it to a particular date (as per the x axis). The date would get filled in the form. Then user can fill flagname and shape and press the button.
On button press, I shall add the flag on the pane.

So essentially sllider is helping in selecting the date where user wants to drop a flag.

Comment: You can add object by [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.rect) and add events line mousemove / mousedown by on() function on element.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Would it be possible for you to show me a fiddle with a very basic of that thing... I will work on the rest... I can handle all basics of highcharts but not the complexity. This would really help me...